# Unable to run the command cuckoo -d after installing the cuckoo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

**ERROR I got is:**

> [cuckoo] CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: Unable to bind ResultServer
> on 192.168.56.1:2042 [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address. This
> usually happens when you start Cuckoo without bringing up the virtual
> interface associated with the ResultServer IP address. Please refer to
> https://cuckoo.sh/docs/faq/#troubles-problem for more information.

**The version of system:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

For this issue I gone through the .conf of cuckoo like cuckoo.conf and vmware.conf files for IP address matching with vmware.

**Installing cuckoo steps followed are**:

1. Installing Python libraries.
2. Virtualization Software.
3. Installing tcpdump.
4. Installing M2Crypto.
5. Installing guacd
   Followed this [document](https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/requirements.html) for pre requirements installation of cuckoo.

After successful installation of requirements gone through [document](https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/installation.html)  for installing the cuckoo.

After installing during configuration that running cuckoo -d command there is error is occurred.
The error occurred in following this [document](https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/cwd.html#configuration) commands.

Steps I followed to resolve the error.

1. Gone through this [steps](https://github.com/CheckPointSW/Cuckoo-AWS/issues/8).
2. Made changes in the cuckoo.conf and vmware.conf files the IP address of resultserver.
3. The IP address is available and able to ping.

Still the error is not resolved.